# BeagleBone Black stops when external powered

Tags: beagleboneblack

I have a BeagleBone Black rev C with kernel 3.8.13-bone50 and Debian OS version 7.5. The problem that I have is that when I connect the external power supply (5 V) and the board is also connected to USB ( for communication with Cloud 9 IDE) it shuts down after almost 5 seconds.

I searched everywhere on Internet for an answer, but nothing. I also displayed the content of the TPS65217 PMIC but nothing. Nothing that could give me an answer why the board is simply shutting down.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some poor quality power supplies might cause the same kind of problem.
Please see below.
http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack#Improper_Power_Down....All_Revisions

Comment: Maybe, but after I changed that bit in the Interrupt Register, everything seems to work perfect. Maybe a bug in software, maybe that interrupt event is interpreted as a shutdown event. Don't know... For now, this quick fix seems to be ok...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the board didn't shutdown after changing a bit in TPS65217 PMIC INT register.

I changed the D5 bit from Interrupt Register from 0 to 1, meaning that no interrupt will be issued when power to AC input is applied or removed.

Command used:

```
i2cset -f -y 0 0x24 0x02 0x20
```